# Is it safe to omit await to let a method run in parallel?

Tags: javascript, express, promise, async-await

Imagine having an expressjs application and having an async tracking method to save in the database certain events:

```js
class Tracking {

    static async track(event) {
       // saves the event in the DB
    }

}
```

Is there some side effect or, in general, something wrong in doing something like this?

```js
app.get('/say-hello-world', function(req, res) {
  Tracking.track("say-hello-world"); // ignore Promise
  console.log("HW");
  Tracking.track("data-logged"); // ignore Promise
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

The tracking code will be executed in parallel and performance should benefit from this. But is there something wrong in doing this (and not using `await`)?

Comment: The only side effect is that your `data-logged` track might complete before your `say-hello-world` track. Also your send might occur before your tracks complete (which depending on your situation may be good or not)

Comment: You might want to checkout [Promise#all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [Promise#allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Comment: in general, there's nothing wrong with not `await`ing an `async` function. But if you don't need to `await`, why even bother with `async`? Also, you cannot `await` in a normal function.

Comment: Also, response will be sent before db writes are completed.

Comment: @kemicofa however this is not a problem as long as the timestamp is created before saving the row in the DB (the async part of the code)

Comment: @marzelin my goal is in fact to avoid that the tracking code slows down the controllers.